# Differentiate $f(x)=\frac{\cos^{-1}\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{2x+7}}$, $-2<x<2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Differentiate $f(x)=\frac{\cos^{-1}\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{2x+7}}$, $-2<x<2$

**My Attempt**
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{\sqrt{2x+7}\frac{d}{dx}\cos^{-1}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)-\cos^{-1}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{2x+7}}{(\sqrt{2x+7})^2}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2x+7}\frac{\frac{-1}{2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}}-\cos^{-1}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)\frac{2}{2\sqrt{2x+7}}}{(\sqrt{2x+7})^2}\\
&=\frac{\frac{-\sqrt{2x+7}.\sqrt{4}}{2\sqrt{4-x^2}}-\frac{\cos^{-1}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)}{\sqrt{2x+7}}}{2x+7}\\
&=\frac{\pm2}{2.\sqrt{2x+7}\sqrt{4-x^2}}-\frac{\cos^{-1}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)}{(2x+7)^{3/2}}\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{2x+7}\sqrt{4-x^2}}-\frac{\cos^{-1}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)}{(2x+7)^{3/2}}\\}
\end{align}
$$
**Result by Mathematica**

```
D[(ArcCos[x/2]/Sqrt[2 x + 7]),x]
```

$$
f'(x)={\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2-x}\sqrt{2+x}\sqrt{7+2x}}-\frac{\arccos\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)}{(7+2x)^{3/2}}}\\
\color{blue}{=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2x+7}\sqrt{4-x^2}}-\frac{\cos^{-1}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)}{(2x+7)^{3/2}}\\}
$$

Mathematica seems to use only the principal root, ie. $\sqrt{4}=+2$ but in that case can I say the given solution is incomplete ?

Or is there any other domain or range considerations which eliminate the other case ?

Comment: We usually take the principal root ($\sqrt4=2$) which clears the minus sign.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire i hv edited the original post. hope it now better explains my doubt. pls check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{4}=|2|=+2$ in line $3-5$ of your solution

**Edit (After OP edited the question):**

The derivativeof $\arccos(x)$ is found to be $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, where we must take the positive sign so that the derivative always has negative sign (Otherwise why even bother with the minus sign too?). So, $\frac{d}{dx}\arccos(x/2)= \frac{-1/2}{\sqrt{1-x^2/4}}$.As you can see, the $\sqrt{4}$ causing all the trouble for you originates from here, and as I said we must only take the positive square root, because the derivative requires it.

Comment: but $\sqrt{4}$ can also be equal to $-2$ right ?. why don't we consider that ?

Comment: @ss1729 I've explained it furthur

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\arccos(x/2)=\frac{-1/2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}}$ thats fine. i dont understand u saying " where we must take the positive sign (Otherwise why even bother with the minus sign too?)". And "we must only take the positive square root, because the derivative requires it", in what way the derivative requires to take the positive square root ?..i'm srry i dont follow.

Comment: The derivative of a function is equal to the slope of the function, and the arccos function is a decreasing function, due to which it's derivative must be negative. If we consider the negative square root, then it will have a positive derivative.

Comment: ohh great. that makes sense now.